# AWS Lambda WebDriverManager Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently getting this error:

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /tmp is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

It seems like it cannot find that directory but as far as I am aware in a lambda it should exist. What am I doing wrong?

Code

```
        String fileName = "tmp";
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
        .targetPath("/"+fileName)
        .setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("/"+fileName);
        options.addArguments(
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-gpu",
                "--enable-javascript",
                "disable-infobars",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--headless",
                "window-size=1400,600",
                "log-level=3");
        this.driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver(options);
        this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        this.driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you solve it?

Comment: @AnderAcosta sorry to give you the bad news but I was forced to switch to python because of this issue. For some reason it is unable to run the driver within the aws environment even if it is placed in /tmp. I'm assume it is something unique to the environment that java is ran in

Comment: Ok, Thanks you very much!